# Linux command to inspect TXT records of a domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, txt-record

Is there a linux shell command that I can use to inspect the TXT records of a domain?

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Dig will also do it quite nicely: `dig -t txt example.com` and if you add the `+short` option you get just the txt record in quote marks with no other cruft.

Comment: According to my DNS manager, I have 4 TXT records - an SPF one with host "@" and then 3 for domainkeys. However, ``dig -t`` only shows the SPF value. Any ideas?

Comment: @NicCottrell and anyone else wondering about this; it is because of the domain you are querying. To view domain keys using dig it would be:
`dkim-selector._domainkey.example.com`

If Google was your email provider: `dig -t txt google._domainkey.example.com`

Comment: And `dkim-selector` is what your email server will write down on the email header, while dmarc is defined to be `_dmarc` prefix .

Comment: The reason for the mismatch, is `dig` doesn't show the sub-domains.  You have to explicitly request that: `dig some._domainkey.foobar.com txt +short`

Answer (score 103):

The [host(1)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=host&sektion=1) command has a nice, terse output:

```
$ host -t txt google.com
google.com descriptive text "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"
$ wajig findfile $(which host)
bind9-host: /usr/bin/host
$
```

With [dig(1)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dig&sektion=1) I "have" to add the "+short" option all the time as well.

(I'm on Debian).

Comment: You can put options in a `~/.digrc` file in order to never add them on command line again.